# Removing PCB from a Dynamixel RX-24F servo?

Tags: dynamixel

For a mod on the Dynamixel RX-24F I need to remove the enclosed PCB. I removed all screws but the PCB doesn't come out easily (without applying more force than I'm comfortable with). It seems to be stuck on the three large solder points in the white area. Has someone experience with this particular servo?

It might be glued/soldered to the case, but I'm not quite certain. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Dynamixel RX-24F PCB]

Comment: Welcome to R.SE - unfortunately, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because quite simply, it has nothing to do with Robotics!

Comment: Maybe I should add context: I need to do this as part of a university project to improve upon the current design of Roboy (see www.roboy.org).

Comment: @Andrew - Maybe this question could be migrated to the Electronics SE?

Comment: I did ponder that, but I'm not sure even there would fit... perhaps (for @grilly) the best bet is contact the manufacturer?